# awk precede pattern match with number of found result

Tags: awk

I would like to precede the search pattern with [result number], irrespective of the line.

Example:

> The function of a paragraph is to mark a pause, setting the paragraph apart from what precedes it. If a paragraph is preceded by a title or subhead, the indent is superfluous and can therefore be omitted

How do I insert the [nth] result before each match?

Desired Output:

> The function of a [1] paragraph is to mark a pause, setting the [2] paragraph apart from what precedes it. If a [3] paragraph is preceded by a title or subhead, the indent is superfluous and can therefore be omitted.

I seem to be almost there but how do I print the surrounding content along with the matches?

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=" "; n=1 } /paragraph/ { print "[" n++ "]"" " $0}' paragraphfile 
[1] paragraph
[2] paragraph
[3] paragraph
```

Comment: `print str` prints `str` + `ORS`, and `ORS` is set to line break by default. And, awk doesn't print records unless you tell it to.

Comment: remove `n=1` and change to `++n` on the solution you will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to modify it a bit to 1) match the output separator to the input separator, and 2) print out the non-matching records as well as the matching ones:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS=" "; n=1 } /paragraph/ { print "[" n++ "]"" " $0} !/paragraph/' paragraphfile
```

Update: Oh, you should probably also modify it to do a full-record match, to avoid e.g. `it` matching `title` and `omitted`, and don't even think about `a`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS=" "; n=1 } /\<a\>/ { print "[" n++ "]"" " $0} !/\<a\>/' paragraphfile
```

Unfortunately, `awk` does not seem to have "case insensitive" matching, so `The` and `the` are "different" words. You'd need to switch to `Perl` to handle that.

Update 2: Or handle "possibly capitalized" yourself on each word:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS=" "; n=1 } /\<[Tt]he\>/ { print "[" n++ "]"" " $0} !/\<[Tt]he\>/' paragraphfile
```

Comment: GNU awk (which you're using for `\<` and `\>`) has case insensitive matching with `IGNORECASE=1` and with any awk you can do `tolower($0) ~ /paragraph/` (or `{lc=tolower($0)} lc ~ /paragraph/` if you need to do multiple matches on lower case $0).